# Using PDF.js throwing a 404 error

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to use pdf.js. I am trying to copy the hello world demo here: http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/1/edit I downloaded the pdf.js from here: https://raw.github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js like in the demo

but when I try and display a pdf I get this error: pdf.worker.js 404 (Not Found)

here is my js:

```
function loadPDFJS(url) {
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
      pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('documentCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
      });
});
}
```

i disable the worker, so what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you cannot use any pre-built pdf.js that you find on the web. You MUST build the js from the git repo yourself. I installed the git command line tool, get the repo, install Node.js, run the make command and use the resulting js files in your code. The instructions on git were clear and concise, and I had only one problem:  I got an "unexpected token" when loading the file.  It was around line 24, my build produced this:

```
PDFJS.build = ''git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
';
```

I just replaced this line with a generic:

```
PDFJS.build = '695e92c';
```

and it all worked fine. (well, I still need to make a viewer)  But i have no errors now.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Very helpful insights indeed. Got stumped with "git is not recognized as...", myself. Why don't you use its own viewer. Its elegant and efficient. Give it a try... cheers :)